# On which Stack Exchange site should I ask a question about GitLab/StackEdit?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I just created a [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab) application to connect it with StackEdit.io. I had to create the GitLab application with `api` scope and I had to uncheck `confidential` due to [1](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/299240) and [2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/07/security-release-gitlab-13-7-2-released/#upgrade-note). I'm not very familiar with [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and was wondering about the privacy risks.

> `api` Grants complete read/write access to the API, including all groups and projects, the container registry, and the package registry.

> `confidential` The application will be used where the client secrets can be kept confidential. Native mobile apps and [single-page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) are considered non-confidential.

Comment: Are you asking because it was not well received on Stack Overflow? It even has a [GitLab "collective"](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q thanks. I have only asked here. I will ask in InfoSec because I'm most interested in the privacy side of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitLab is a web application and we have a [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) site. It even has a [gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab) tag.

> For questions about GitLab - a repository manager which lets teams collaborate on code.

There's also an [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site if your questions are specifically about security. That site has an [oauth](/questions/tagged/oauth) tag.

> OAuth is an open standard for authorizing access to data. It is a service that is complementary to, but distinct from, OpenID.

As always check the site's help centres (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help and https://security.stackexchange.com/help) and maybe look at the existing questions in those tags to see if your question is a good fit.